# Beginner Android: R file in Fragment example on Developer page generates unexpected results

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I am very new to java and android programming. I was working through the developer page trying to figure out the goings on and the example found at this address: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/creating.html
produced results that I could not explain. Specifically, the R file generates a couple of variables in the ID subpart that I could not find in any of the resource files. I don't know if I am looking in the wrong place or perhaps it pre generated not from the provided xmls? I am just trying to understand the dynamics of R file generation and interaction with the resource files and am having trouble reconciling that example.

Comment: What are the names of the variables? Are you sure you looked it in all the resources files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an android project the R class is automatically updated or generated when every time you build your project. By default the eclipse builds or compiles your code automatically when you save changes or when you hit ctrl + s. So any changes in your resources R is updated. When you specify new ids, layouts, drawables, menus, strings, styles etc. android adds a reference static integer in your R class.

example:

```
public static final class id {
    public static final int image=0x7f070001;
    public static final int input=0x7f070000;
    public static final int menu_settings=0x7f070002;
}
```

When you add @+id/myname R will be updated to...

```
public static final class id {
    public static final int image=0x7f070001;
    public static final int input=0x7f070000;
    public static final int menu_settings=0x7f070002;
    public static final int myname=0x<something>;
}
```

R class is used also to access or as a reference when you want to find, set or get.

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //this will set the layout in the activity where R class points out to the integer reference in the R class which somehow used by the system to get the xml layout activity_main

 someView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.picture) //R points to the integer reference of image which then the system interprets the someView's background is set by the image file picture under drawable resource.
```

I hope this helps and welcome to android :)

Answer (score 0):

The IDs generated in the R-file cannot be found up, they are generated through algorithms, you have to imagine them like hashcodes, which are unique generated